# Folder name clashing with html page (using htaccess)

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a static html website and I'm using .htaccess to clean up the url by removing the .html from the address.

The issue is when I visit "example.com/path" it clashes with the folder "path" but when I choose to manually enter example.com/path.html I will get the page loading just fine.

The URLs inside the "path" folder are working fine as well with "example.com/path/page1" both with and without .html file extension.

My only alternative just now is to change the folder name from the file name as subtle as possible until I find a solution.

I've had a look at related questions being asked as well as a bit of research on conditions to put into my .htaccess file but having no luck.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT ***

htaccess file ..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk$1 [L,R=301]
```

Just returning a 403.

Comment: show your `.htaccess` code.

Comment: Updated original post for you.

Comment: please have a look on my answer and do let me know if still any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Note : Don't forget to replace **RewriteBase**. As of now i have added **/** bca my project is in root folder. You can simply add folder name like below

```
 RewriteBase /yourfoldername/
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: It turns from a 403 to a 500 error now.

Would it be preferred to have the original file inside the folder which I'm trying to show or is it best to leave it at root/public_html?

Comment: you can put your project in any folder no need to put in root. only you need to change RewriteBase / to your folder name as i explain in my answer.

Comment: add following line at the top of .htaccess file `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` at the end.

Comment: Same thing applies, will there be any point in changing the chmod of the folder? The conditions set overall on my htaccess is removing .html extension and forcing https (forgot to add comments).